# Chemfig - Name some compounds under a single label

Tags: formatting, chemfig

I know within the `chemfig` package compounds can be named with the command `\chemname`. Is there a way to label some compounds under a single label? For example, put a label "Reactants" under the reactants in a reactions scheme.

In the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig{R-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]R}
\arrow{0}[,.5]
\chemfig{R'-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]R'}
\arrow{0}[,1.5]
\chemfig{R'-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]R}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

I can put a label under the third compound with `\chemname`, but how can I put a single label under the first two compounds?

Comment: If you're creating a scheme with `\schemestart ... \schemestop` you can place any label you like anywhere you like as if it where a compound, e.g. using invisible arrows for positioning.  Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: Just edited for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place the first two compounds in a `\subscheme{...}` the whole subscheme gets a unique name that you can refer to in an arrow using the `\arrow{@<name>--)` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

% uncomment to see the names:
% schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
\subscheme{
  \chemfig{R-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]R}
  \arrow{0}[,.5]
  \chemfig{R'-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]R'}
}
\arrow{0}[,1.5]
\chemfig{R'-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]R}
% use an invisible arrow pointing downwards to place the label text:
\arrow(@c1--){0}[-90,.1]
Below the first two compounds
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Nice and clean trick. One question, I assume that the identifier "@c1--" is internal and systematic, rather that being arbitrarily defined by the user? Because it is no defined along with the subscheme.

Comment: If you uncomment `\schemedebug{true}` you will see the the compounds are named by `chemfig` automatically with `c1`, `c2`, ... in order of appearance. You can give them names of your own, though, again with the arrow syntax `\arrow(<name1>--<name2>)` (without `@`). If you like I'll add an example.

Answer (score 3):

I know Clemens loves `\arrow{0}` but his solution sounds complicated to me. Why don't you use `\schemestart...\schemestop` inside `\chemname`, which seems more natural?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemname{%
    \schemestart
        \chemfig{R-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]R}
        \arrow{0}[,.5]
        \chemfig{R'-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]R'}
    \schemestop
    }
    {One long name here!}
\arrow(.base east--.base west){0}[,1.5]
\chemfig{R'-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]R}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution as well. But I have a little issue, the following command: \arrow(.base east--.base west){0}[,1.5] gets an undefined error since it's outside the scheme block. Which package do I need to use so such commands can be used outside these blocks?

Comment: @B3y0nd3r there are _two_ schemes - an outer and an inner scheme